# Probability distribution. Is this a geometric distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A factory packs items in 45 unit boxes, which 5 of those items are defective. Before ship it, a box is selected randomly. Also, 3 items are selected randomly. If the 3 items are in perfect state, the box is considered to have passed the test. If the box didn't pass the test, the procedure is repeated with other box unit finds another box that pass the test. The probability distribution for the total of boxes to check is ...

Is this a Geometric distribution? And what is the value of p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it could be geometric. The value of $p$ is the chance of success in this case is 3 items in perfect state which is $$\frac{{40\choose 3}}{{45\choose 3}}=\frac{40\times39\times38}{45\times44\times43}=0.696265$$

If $X$ is the number of failures then $$X\sim \text{Geometric}(.69)$$

The total number of boxes to check is one added to this, has pmf

$$\Pr(X=x)=(.31)^{x-1}(.69),x=1,2,3,...$$

I guess it wouldn't matter if you just kept checking the same box or actually a different box each time...